# Help with a AWK function

Tags: awk

I have problems with AWK command. When I used this code is:

```
$ awk '{a[NR]=$1} 
 END {for (i=0;i<NR;i++)  
      {B=a[i+1];A=a[i];C=(B-A);D=int(C/16)} 
      {for (j=0;j<=D;j++) 
         {if(C!=16) {print t=A;A=A+16;B} else {print A}}
 }}' 19.txt
```

My input file "19.txt" is :

```
1510
1526
1542
1558
1614
1630
1646
1702
1802
```

I got this out:

```
1702
1718
1734
1750
1766
1782
1798
```

My code only use the difference of the last lines, why?? I want to complete the spaces between consecutive lines, where the different between lines is equal to 16, similar to this:

```
1510
1526
1542
1558
----
1574
1590
1606
----
1614
1630
1646
----
1662
1678
1694
----
1702
----
1718
1734
1750
1766
1782
1798
----
1802
```

Answer (score 3):

This produces the output you're looking for, and it does not have to store the whole file in memory.

```
awk -v diff=16 ' 
    NR>1 && $1-prev > diff { 
        print "----" 
        while ($1-prev > diff) { 
            prev += diff 
            print prev 
        } 
        print "----" 
    }  
    { 
        print 
        prev = $1 
    } 
' 19.txt
```

Ask me if there's anything in there you don't understand.

Comment: thank you for your answer, but it's not exactly I want. I don't need print "---" only the sum of16 to each line, like this: 1558 + 16=1574 (print 1574); 1574 +16=1590 (print 1590); 1590+16=1606...so on, until the $1 is less that prev, like 1606 < 1614 (print 1614) and continue...(1630-1614)=16 (print 1614); (1646-1630)=16 (then print 1630 ); (1702-1646)=56, 56 different to 16, then print (1646; 1646+16=1662;1662+16=78;....)

Comment: So, just remove the two `print "----"` lines

Comment: I'd like to offer a little script shorting `awk -v diff=16 ' 
    prev && $1 > prev { 
        print "----" ;
        while ($1 > prev) { 
            print prev ;
            prev += diff 
        } ;
        print "----" 
    }  
    { 
        print ;
        prev = $1 + diff
    } 
'`